# Android Map View

Tags: android

In my application if i press a button map is loaded in my layout.again i press the button i got error like this.

onlu one map is added to a single map activity . how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a programming trick to avoid this.

booleanVar = false;
onButtonClick

if(! booleanVar){

load the map .
  set a booleanVar to true.
}

Comment: Check if mGoogleMap !=null